Protecting Routes in an Edge-Runtime with T3 Stack / Vercel AI SDK
How can I authorize users on my OpenAI route so that not everyone can call the API? When I worked with getserversesseion I got the message that the crypto library was not found.
api/completion/route.ts
import { createOpenAI } from "@ai-sdk/openai";
import { Ratelimit } from "@upstash/ratelimit";
import { Redis } from "@upstash/redis";
import { streamText } from "ai";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { env } from "process";

const ratelimit = new Ratelimit({
  redis: Redis.fromEnv(),
  limiter: Ratelimit.slidingWindow(1, "0 s"),
});

export const runtime = "edge";

const openai = createOpenAI({
  apiKey: env.OPEN_AI_API_KEY,
});

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  const ip = req.headers.get("x-forwarded-for") ?? "";
  const { success, reset } = await ratelimit.limit(ip);

  const { prompt }: { prompt: string } = (await req.json()) as {
    prompt: string;
  };

  if (!success) {
    console.log("Rate limited");
    const now = Date.now();
    const retryAfter = Math.floor((reset - now) / 1000);
    return new NextResponse(
      "Du hast zu viele Anfragen gestellt, KI Anfragen sind alle 60 Sekunden möglich.",
      {
        status: 420,
        headers: {
          ["retry-after"]: `${retryAfter}`,
        },
      },
    );
  }

  const result = await streamText({
    model: openai("gpt-4o"),
    system: "You are a helpful assistant.",
    prompt,
  });

  return result.toDataStreamResponse();
}

This is my route - works well bot not really secure - I think.
Calling the endpoint with vercels AI Sdk
 const { completion, complete, error } = useCompletion({
    api: "/api/completion",
  });

  return (
    <Card>
      <CardHeader>
        <Button onClick={async () => await complete("test")}>test</Button>
        {completion}

How can I protect this endpoint? Or is there a better way to integrate this?

getServerSession is used on the server environment. you might be using on the client side and that is why you are getting "the crypto library was not found"
